# How to add results from statistical tests in R to my existing dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a relatively large dataframe (147 rows by 648 columns) - from this I have done a pairwise t test between two of the columns, resulting in the standard t test output given by R.

I need to add the results from this t test as a new column to my dataframe, but cannot work out how to do so? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a small example of what you have done (and ideally what you want as a result), e.g.: `set.seed(123); dat <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=sample(10))` ? That should give you a `data.frame` with 2 columns which you could use as an example here.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail , Using the data.frame you provided as an example. I have done a two-sample t test, giving the following output                                          
 
'Welch Two Sample t-test
data:  dat$a and dat$b
t = 0, df = 18, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.844662  2.844662
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
      5.5       5.5'

I would like to add the results from this t test (i.e p value, confidence intervals) as new columns to the existing dataframe (dat in this case). Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible. You have 10 rows in the original data (more in your real data) and one set of results (i.e. - 1 'row' of information) to add into back to the `data.frame`.